# Разрыв соединения с сокетом

Tags: сокет, c++, linux

Написал сервер под линукс. Запускаю, подключаюсь к нему через браузер.
Когда закрываю вкладку, сервер падает на следующей строчке

```
if (send(s, &message[0], message.length(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    throw std::string("Unable to send() string: ") + toString(errno);
}
```

Исключение не ловится.

Comment: message - это std::string?

При закрытии сокета send может возвратить `EPIPE`, а может и сигнал послать.

Comment: да, std::string.

Comment: Добавил проверку, что возвращает send

    int res = send(s, &message[0], message.length(), 0);
    std::cout << "res " << res << std::endl;

Так ничего на экран и не выводит. Приложение падает при отправке сообщения. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Как уже сказал @KoVadim, скорее всего сигнал SIGPIPE. Т.е. нет читателя (клиент уже вызвал close() на своей стороне).

Можете попробовать в Linux передавать в `send()` флаг `MSG_NOSIGNAL`.
Или заблокируйте этот сигнал (sigprocmask()/sighold()) или перехватывайте (sigaction()/signal()) или можете игнорировать (sigaction()/signal()).

А  SOCKET_ERROR у Вас это -1?

Comment: да, это -1

Comment: @feelGood, я Вам там кучу советов написал, а сам обычно делаю просто

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

где-нибудь в начале программы.

Comment: да, спасибо, помогло

Comment: Только не забудьте (см. `man 7 signal`)

    During  an  execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals
    are reset to the default; 
    the dispositions of ignored  signals are  left  unchanged.

(если у Вас серьезный сервер).